# Setting different vertical spacing in text and math mode

Tags: cases, vertical-spacing

I'd like to vertically stretch the spaces between lines in the text parts of my documents a bit more, while keeping the math mode parts as close as usual, avoiding excessively high cases environments, for example. I tried looking at the \setspace package documentation but I didn't find anything useful..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass... ` to `\end{document})` that we can compile that shows your problem and what you have done to try to fix it. We can invent a MWE that probably will have nothing to do with your problem, but we won't waste time doing that. -GOM